# submit form and load new page

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a JQM page to send an email via a form and then redirect to a new page. I have the mail part working fine, but the redirect not so much! After the form has been submitted and mail sent, the page basically just refreshes instead of loading the new page. I've tried many different things using the code `header('Location:myredirectpage');` but nothing works.

The following php code is located below my closing HTML tag at the bottom of my page.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['mr'])) { 

    $to = "myemailaddress";
    $subject = "Subject";
    $content = ""
                    ."Survey Details"."\n\n"
                    ."How did you hear about us: ".$_POST['mr']."\n";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <myemailaddress>\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);

    $sendit= @mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);

    if($sendit){

      header('Location:myredirectpage');

    }else{ echo "Email failed to send";}
}

?>
```

Comment: Using error surpression is considered bad practice, I'd recommend removing the @ symbol from before your mail() function

Comment: Why are you sending the mail twice (mail() and @mail())

Comment: the url routing for jqm is different from normal webpages

Comment: I was not aware that I was sending it twice. I assumed the $sendit= was linked to my if($sendit) statement. Only one mail is being received though.

Comment: No, $sendit = ... is assigning the variable $signit to the response from mail(), which will be either true or false (depending on whether the email got sent). This should send the email twice. As to why you only receive it once, may be down to spam filters or the way the mail server is setup.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your page after it has been sent, you need something in the following format:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Change index.php to the FILENAME of what you want to get to.

This can be a full URL such as http://google.com

Comment: Thanks. I do actually make use of a proper URL in my code, just indicated it with 'myredirectpage'.

Comment: Is there the space there?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? If not, turn it on using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of the file (after `<?php`)

Comment: Thanks Bowersbros. Add the code but no errors showing. If you don't mind, might be best if you take a look at the page: http://www.ecaddy.co.za/gosurveyus/luckyfish/mr.php

Comment: For me, it simply refreshes the page with every selection. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: After making the selection and hitting the NEXT button it's supposed to load a different page determined by this code: header('Location:http://gosurvey.us/s/125/l/112');

Comment: Thanks Bowersbros for your help as well as the edit but still not working.

Comment: Are you able to post the full file in pastie.org or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the mail twice : `mail(...)` then `@mail(...)`.
Also using `@mail(...)` with `@` is considered bad practice.

Comment: There is no output from this file, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `header('Location:myredirectpage');` use

```
echo '<script>window.location = 'yourpage'</script>'
```

Try this

Comment: Don't do this. For a start, It will use more HTTP requests than necessary, and is often slower. Also, it can be bypassed by users not having javascript enabled.